# Inconsistency between postscript encoding when injecting staple commands

Tags: .net, pdf, printing, postscript

I am encoding the files in PostScript and sending this directly to a printer (Cannon Image Runner Adv 8105 PRO) using the command line copy process

I have obtained the PPD file for the printer ([CNADV8105E1.PPD](http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010873.asp)), and I am injecting the PS commands into my PS file for stapling as defined in the PPD `<</Staple 3 /StapleDetails <</Type 21 /Position (1PLU)>> >> systemdict /setpagedevice get exec` I am injecting the staple command in the `%%BEGINSETUP` block

When my PS file is encoded by acrobat reader (printed using reader to a redmon/ghostscript printer) the staple commands work successfully, however this option is not suitable for the overall desired result as an acrobat reader window opens for each document printed (if multiple documents are printed)

To avoid having to open acrobat reader for each document I am passing the pdf through a .net library (xpdf – pdftops) This encodes the output in a different format of postscript which the printer interprets correctly and prints successfully however, when injecting the staple commands as defined by the PPD into this encoding, the stapling does not work (in fact, no longer are the pages held in escrow before being transferred to the output tray, they are in fact deposited in the output tray as soon as they are drawn)

I have tried other commands from the PPD in this encoding and they do work (such as letterhead)

- Is there a syntax guide for xpdf output postscript so I can rewrite the staple command?
- Is there another staple command I could use?
- How does my printer intepret 2 apparently very different syntax of postscript successfully?

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There is some confusion in your posting. You say you are modifying the PostScript program by inserting (device-specific) staple instructions. You then say you are printing the file using Acrobat Reader. That can't be the case because Acrobat doesn't handle PostScript.... Also you later mention converting PDF to PostScript, so there is obviously a step missing here.

I'm not at all sure why you would be printing from Acrobat Reader to Ghostscript via RedMon, when your printer is a PostScript printer. Why not print direct ?

If you are creating a PDF file, then the Staple commands will be lost, they can't be preserved in PDF. So whatever is 'working', it isn't to do with your original modifications, the PostScript being sent to your printer won't bear any relation to your original PostScript program.

The output of pdftops is a PostScript program (yes, PostScript is a programming language), so inserting random stuff into it probably won't work. Its not a different 'format', its a different program altogether. Your different 'PostScript formats' are simply different programs using the same language.

In fact, modifying a PostScript program is quite difficult, and unless you are in a closed workflow of some kind it may be impossible to do reliably. Note that any line beginning with '%'in a PostScript program is a comment, and may not be present unless your file is DSC conformant.

So:

1) How are you creating ('encoding') the PostScript program ? Why can't you simply insert the Staple commands as required when the PostScript is created ? If you are creating the PostScript by printing, then use the PPD (or WPD) for the printer you intend to use.

2) If you do modify the PostScript program, by adding Staple commands, what happens if you send that to the printer ?

3) What is the conversion to PDF step for, and where does it fit into the described workflow ?

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for your response ...

We are using Acrobat Reader to render the postscript. When the original document (word, excel etc) is printed via the redmon/ghostcript printer initially, and a postscript program is generated, this is then converted from postscript to PDF (I guess we could use a postscript renderer in the application's GUI but we are using Acrobat Reader for now)

I am indeed in a closed/controlled workflow

1) I am opening the file in acrobat reader by invoke the process, passing the file name in as an argument for printing. The default printer will be the redmon/gs ...

Comment: ... printer as mentioned earlier. When I edit the postscript that results from this and copy this directly to the physical printer the stapling works

2) It works when the postscript is generated from "Print From Acrobat > Redmond/GS printer > add staple commands > send to printer. It doesn't work when "invoke pdftops process with parameter of pdf file > add staple commands > send to printer"

3) As mentioned before, the conversion to PDF is used for rendering the file and portability if needs be. I understand that if I do this after adding the staple commands ...

Comment: they will be lost. For the final print, no conversion to PDF occurs

Comment: @Alex ITYM Acrobat *Distiller*, not *Reader*. The Reader, as its name indicates merely *reads* the PDF files. Distiller performs the conversion from PS to PDF.

Comment: OK so the PDF is only intended for viewing, so lets forget about that totally. The first point is that you seem to be putting a needless conversion in place. You print from an application to RedMon intending to pass that to Ghostscript, apparently in order to get a PostScript file by using either the pswrite or ps2write device (you don't say what you are doing with GS here). The data you are sending to Ghostscript is *already* a PostScript program. Ghostscript only interprets PDF or PostScript, so using it in this fashion is not required. <continues>

Comment: In fact the proper way to do this is to print to your final intended printer, setting it up with stapling as you wish. The PostScript program should then be created with the required stapling already present. You can take that file and send it straight to your printer. You can take the same file and convert it to PDF using either Ghostscript or Acrobat *Distiller* (as luser droog points out above). It seems to me that your current process has some steps that you don't need and are causing you a problem. <continues again>

Comment: I don't see why you are insisting on printing the *PDF* file, rather than printing the *PostScript* file that was produced in the first step. If you really must print the PDF file, then send it to Ghostscript, use the same device setup you were originally using (either pswrite or ps2write) and use that to create PostScript which you apparently can already modify. My guess about the pdftops output is that it is not producing DSC compliant PostScript, so you can't make assumptions about its content. Such programs are potentially extremely hard to modify.

Comment: First comment ... Sorry for the slow response, I need to set up email alerts for this thread!

Comment: Thanks again for the responses. You are correct, the redmon environment variable does indeed get written straight to disk - apologies for my confusion on this matter. GS is used after this step to convert the postscript to pdf (for viewing)... When you mention the proper way to do what I need to do is to print to my final printer and send the resultant file direct to my printer; how/where in this workflow will the file be stored?

Comment: I am insisting on printing the PDF file, as the pdf for viewing can be joined with other PDFs into one (so I guess not JUST for viewing then ... sorry) and have pages removed and reordered and saved down to another PDF. I have tried passing this resultant PDF to ghostscript using the pswrite devices, however the PS program that is output does not have the `&&BEGIN SETUP` blocks that are required for me to inject the staple command to.... I appreciate your hint about the DSC compliance, I will have a look into this. Thanks again

Comment: The ps2write device is much more flexible, produces better output *and* (in recent versions) produces DSC-conformant PostScript....

Comment: Thanks Ken, I will revisit that device. I had tried it during my initial investigation but might be able to make it working knowing what I do now. If successful I will update the answer and mark as answered. Thanks, Alex

Comment: Tried the ps2write device, with included staple command. The result was the same as with pdftops in that the printer changed its behavior slightly but still did not staple. Next step, get in touch with printer manufacturer. Thanks again, Alex

Comment: I'll be interested to hear what they say, and if you get a resolution to the problem